# Using debug symbols with perf

Tags: symbols, perf, dwarf

I monitor a process on a PowerPC system in order to extract performance information.
How I can load the debug symbols of this process?
I use the following command

```
perf record -g dwarf -p 4591
```

and I take an error that the "dwarf cannot be found (no such file or directory)"
Could you please give me a hint how to load debug information about the functions that have been called when the report is generated?

Comment: Please always post the verbatim error message instead of paraphrasing! Makes it much more likely that you get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an [old version of perf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/perf-record) which do not support `-g dwarf` but only `-g` (without argument) i.e. it does not support DWARF unwinding.

Comment: This was the case for me while trying to develop a Qt application on an older Linux kernel (3.4). When Built-in Performance Analyzer tool of Qt Creator is invoked, it tries to launch `PerfParser` with `--call-graph lbr` and the following error is seen:

`lbr: No such file or directory
lbr: Terminated`

Answer (score 2):

```
perf record -g dwarf -p 4591
```

These days the correct option to chose a method is `--call-graph` whereas `-g` is only a flag to enable call stacks with it's default method `fp`.

from `man perf-record`.

```
-g
    Enables call-graph (stack chain/backtrace) recording.

--call-graph
    Setup and enable call-graph (stack chain/backtrace) recording,
    implies -g.  Default is "fp".

    Allows specifying "fp" (frame pointer) or "dwarf"
    (DWARF's CFI - Call Frame Information) or "lbr"
    (Hardware Last Branch Record facility) as the method to collect
    the information used to show the call graphs.

    In some systems, where binaries are build with gcc
    --fomit-frame-pointer, using the "fp" method will produce bogus
    call graphs, using "dwarf", if available (perf tools linked to
    the libunwind or libdw library) should be used instead.
    Using the "lbr" method doesn't require any compiler options. It
    will produce call graphs from the hardware LBR registers. The
    main limitation is that it is only available on new Intel
    platforms, such as Haswell. It can only get user call chain. It
    doesn't work with branch stack sampling at the same time.

    When "dwarf" recording is used, perf also records (user) stack dump
    when sampled.  Default size of the stack dump is 8192 (bytes).
    User can change the size by passing the size after comma like
    "--call-graph dwarf,4096".
```

By the way, try `fp` first - it's much more efficient, but doesn't work well with optimized binaries (e.g. `--fomit-frame-pointer`). Also this has very little to do with debug information. If you do not need to know the stack trace, you needn't add `-g`.